# I get a 'function object has no attribute 'shape'' error for a parameter passed to a function when that parameter is clearly not an object

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have implemented a loss function for a neural network. Here is the function definition -

```
def calculate_cost (Y, prediction, activation_output = 'sigmoid'):
    """
    Calculates the cost.

    Takes in the output labels and the prediction from forward propagation, as well as the activation function of the output layer.
    Returns the cost.
    """
    m = Y.shape[1]

    if activation_output.lower() == 'sigmoid':
        cost = (1/m)*np.sum(Y*np.log(prediction) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-prediction))

    if activation_output.lower() == 'softmax':
        cost = (1/m)*np.sum(np.sum(Y*np.log(prediction), axis = 0, keepdims = True))

    return cost
```

Here Y is a numpy array of the labelled outputs for the input dataset. I get an error on the line where I declare the variable m.

```
<ipython-input-6-0c38b0031612> in calculate_cost(Y, prediction, activation_output)     
     10     """
---> 11     m = Y.shape[1]
     12 
     13     if activation_output.lower() == 'sigmoid':

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I'm calling the model() function I have implemented which takes in the input data set and output labels, along with a few hyperparameters and starts training a model on the given data sets. The function definition for the model() function is -

```
def model (X, Y, architecture, activation_functions, learning_rate = 0.001, print_cost = True, number_of_iterations = 10000):
    """
    Takes in the training set X, the labels Y, and all the required parameters and trains the defined model for the given number of iterations.
    Prints the cost if print_cost is true.
    """
    costs = []
    number_of_layers = len(architecture) - 1

    parameters = initialize_parameters(architecture)

    for i in range(number_of_iterations):

        prediction, cache = forward_propagation(X, parameters, number_of_layers, activation_functions)
        cost = calculate_cost(Y, prediction, activation_functions[-1])
```

The error occurs on this last line.

I am calling this function as follows -

```
X_train = pd.read_csv('training_set.csv', header = None).to_numpy()
Y_train = pd.read_csv('training_labels.csv', header = None).to_numpy()

model(X_train, Y_train, [10,5,5,1], ['relu','relu','relu','relu','sigmoid'])
```

The second input, Y_train, is passed to the calculate_cost() function. Y_train is clearly a numpy array:/

Comment: Can you also post how/where you call the function ? In first sight, it seems you try to feed a `function` as `Y` instead of an `array`.

Comment: The error says `Y` is a `function` not an array,

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your error

Comment: The code seems correct, can you just check the type of Y in every function call and wherever you use it? That should show where the problem is.